# Display Message Label on form when form goes into EDIT mode

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form that allows data entry with an EDIT button on it.

When the EDIT button is pressed, the form goes into edit mode, but I would like to have a label or similar ON the form that becomes visible displaying "EDIT MODE".

I'm new to Access events and VBA etc so any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Below is the code I found that worked for what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code I found that works for what I wanted to do. There are also a few little font and forecolor codes in the label.

On the firm I also created a label so I could determine what value was being updated from the combo box.

Create this code on the actual combo box itself on the AfterUpdate event

```
Private Sub ActivityCriteria_AfterUpdate()
'Create a label and show in the label what is being selected on the label caption
AcMessage.ForeColor = vbRed
'vbCrLf equals line break
AcMessage.Caption = "Value passed: " & vbCrLf & ActivityCriteria.Text
AcMessage.FontWeight = Heavy

'Run If statement to determine the value of the combo list
If Me.ActivityCriteria.Text() = "IA - Individual Assist" Then
'Provide the options if the statement is true
AcMessage.ForeColor = vbBlue
AcMessage.FontWeight = Heavy
Me.IndividualName.Visible = True
Me.MemberOrgName.Visible = False
Me.ExtOrganisationName.Visible = False

    'Ask the ElseIf statement to determine next value from the combo list
    ElseIf Me.ActivityCriteria.Text() = "MA - Members Assisted" Then
    'Provide the options if the statement is true
    AcMessage.ForeColor = vbMagenta
    AcMessage.FontWeight = Heavy
    Me.IndividualName.Visible = False
    Me.MemberOrgName.Visible = True
    Me.ExtOrganisationName.Visible = False

        'Another ElseIf statement to determine next value from the combo list
        ElseIf Me.ActivityCriteria.Text() = "CA - Community Assisted" Then
        'Provide the options for this statement if true
        AcMessage.ForeColor = RGB(255, 128, 0)
        AcMessage.FontWeight = Heavy
        Me.IndividualName.Visible = False
        Me.MemberOrgName.Visible = False
        Me.ExtOrganisationName.Visible = True

            'Otherwise in all other cases
            Else
            'Do this option
            AcMessage.ForeColor = RGB(138, 43, 266)
            AcMessage.FontWeight = Heavy
            Me.IndividualName.Visible = False
            Me.MemberOrgName.Visible = False
            Me.ExtOrganisationName.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

After spending several days on this it appears to work well, and I hope it will help someone else or at lease give them ideas of what is possible.